# Insert, Update, Create Table, queries not working in wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been using wampserver for a php project, but DML queries are not working for me. Here is some test code I've been using

```
$query='insert into register(first_name) values("swagmaster")';

echo($query);

$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$query);

echo"<br>$query";

if(mysqli_real_query($connection,"'".$query."'")===TRUE)
{
    echo"woohoo!";
}
else
{
    echo"query failed";
}
echo(mysqli_error($connection));
```

I get the following output when i run this:

> insert into register(first_name) values("swagmaster")
>   insert into register(first_name) values(\"swagmaster\") query failed
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''insert into register(first_name) values(\"swagmaster\")'' at line 1

However, a select statement works fine. I suspect the issue is in mysql settings. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Using a combination of your tips, the query is now working. Thank you all!

Comment: Then try `$query="insert into register(first_name) values('swagmaster')";` using reversed quotes. And then `if(mysqli_real_query($connection,$query)===TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `register` SET `fieldname`='{$vaue}',`field2`='{$value2}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query from

```
$query='insert into register(first_name) values("swagmaster")';
```

to

```
$query="insert into register(first_name) values('swagmaster')";
```

Also as Fred-ii said you dont need to add `'` here

```
if(mysqli_real_query($connection,"'".$query."'")===TRUE)
```

change to

```
if(mysqli_real_query($connection,$query)===TRUE)
```

Comment: sorry about that, i was trying random things hoping that they work. i had the above code previously, but it did not work.

Comment: If you want to play around then play with the logic not with the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You used

`$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$query);`

But this escaped all quotes in query. This is incorrect. For protected fro SQL injection you should use escape function only to value instead query.

For your example you not need this string.

But if you use variables then you should use it

```
$value = "swagmaster";
$value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
$query='insert into register(first_name) values("' . $value . '")';
```

In $query is already correct query. And add quotes is incorrect. Just use

`if(mysqli_real_query($connection, $query)===TRUE)`

Comment: thanks for the advice with escaping, but it did not resolve the issue